# Volley :Post request is not working : Error Unexpected Response code 404

Tags: android, http-headers, android-volley, restful-url

Trying to register user but getting error Unexpected response code 404, while the URL is correct , parameters are also correct , I've tested it on POSTMAN and it's working fine, but when I am trying to make a request it gives :

> E/Volley: [19358] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for GIVEN URL

It seems the parameter is not attaching with the URL, but I also made a custom request but that also doesn't work, please help with it.

**Note:** the only header is  "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`";

```
 private void registerUser()
                {
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, APIReference.USER_REGISTRATION_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                Toast.makeText(mContext,jsonObject.getString("status"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                showSnackbar(jsonObject.getString("status"));

                                JSONObject object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                                User user = new User(object.getString("user_id"),
                                        object.getString("user_name"),
                                        object.getString("user_email"),
                            object.getString("user_phone_no"));

                Toast.makeText(mContext,String.valueOf(jsonObject.getJSONObject("response")),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("response error : ", String.valueOf(error));
            showSnackbar(String.valueOf(error));
         }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_name", mUserName);
            params.put("user_email", mUserEmail);
            params.put("user_password", mUserPassword);
            params.put("user_phone_no", mUserMobileNo);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded,charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded,charset=utf-8";
        }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext).getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: in getHeaders() you need to put the api key too, and please provide what rest api are you trying to use , or check if the page have a troubleshoot with those errors telling you what it should be

Comment: Try changing content type   to application/json

Comment: Are you getting null on this log " response error " @harpalSingh

Comment: @IDroid Api is not using any key, or auth header except content type=x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @Abhishekkumar no error code is 404 : and message is volley.Clienterror

Comment: have you tried to print url and params and checked?

Comment: can you refer the page that you are using the REST Api please?

Comment: @UpendraShah yes params and url are not null

Comment: @IDroid {
    "status": "success",
    "message": "User added successfully",
    "response": {
        "user_id": "11",
        "user_name": "manish",
        "user_email": "manish123@gmail.com",
        "user_phone_no": "9876543217"
    }

Comment: Can you post you log here @harpalSingh

Comment: @Abhishekkumar 01-25 19:24:12.259 16589-17934/com.bhagat.socialmediachat E/Volley: [20604] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for URL_HERE  ...................01-25 19:24:12.269 16589-16589/com.bhagat.socialmediachat D/response error :: com.android.volley.ClientError

Comment: URL and params are same as you desired? because 404 means the url is not getting. Url  are local or live ? if local than you must have in same network.

Comment: @Upendra Shah YES they are same

Comment: IT is live, URL is correct also params are , I've checked it so many times

Comment: please provide the url from where are you calling the rest api please, not an example response

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes `JSON` URL response working fine but in Android its showing error on Volley Library, because of Timeout. So you have to set the time.

Add this code on your Volley Code :

```
private static final int MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS = 60000;

 eventoReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Full Code it is :

```
String url = urlhere;
    Log.e("URL", "" + url);

    StringRequest eventoReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("RESPONSE", response.toString());

                    utils.hideDialog();
                    try {
                        JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response);

                         //code here
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error: ", "" + error.getMessage());
            utils.hideDialog();
            utils.showtoast("Please try again...");

        }
    });
    eventoReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    // Añade la peticion a la cola
    AppController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(eventoReq);
```

Comment: this is a generic example but not solving op problem

Comment: i'm getting same issue , solved by adding this code. @IDroid, Let check to harpal

Comment: @Abhishekkumar That i already done, that's not the issue, btw thanks